# setTimeout function does not affect anything

Tags: javascript, html

So I am trying to use setTimeout on one of the functions triggered by a button, but no matter how I format it or where I put it, it just doesn't work.

On the website, there is a magic 8 ball a user would click, the animation would play, and then 3 seconds later (that's how long the animation is) a popup with an answer would appear. Everything works except the delay for a popup to appear. No matter if I use the setTimeout function or not, the popup appears right away after clicking the button. Is there something I am missing or doing wrong?

Any help would be appreciated!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Magic 8 Ball</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
  </head>
    <body>  
        <h1>Magic 8 Ball</h1>
        <p>Ask a question and click on the Magic 8 Ball to reveal the answer</p>
        
        <div class = "8ball">
            <button id = "8bbtn" onclick="spin(); show()"> 
                <video id="video1" width="800">
                <source src="./media/8ball.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            </video> 
            </button>
        </div>
        
        <div id = 'splashscrn'>
            <h1>THE ANSWER</h1>
        </div>
        
        <script> 
            var myVideo = document.getElementById("video1");
            var popup = document.getElementById("splashscrn");
            
            function spin() {  
                myVideo.play(); 
            }
            
            function show() {
                popup.style.display = 'block';
                setTimeout(show, 3000);
            }
        </script>
        
    </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Well, you call `show`. `show` first displays the popup. **Then `show` sets a timeout to call `show` again.** `show` then displays the popup. Then it sets a timeout again to call itself again…

Answer (score 0):

You are calling both `spin` and `show` here: `onclick="spin(); show()"`. So the popup is shown immediately. The `setTimeout` function call inside `show` is calling `show` again after 3 seconds, which visibly does nothing (since the popup is already shown by the call before).

I would suggest to remove `show()` from the onclick handler and instead move the `setTimeout` function at the end of your `spin` function.

Comment: Oh my goodness thank you so much! I've been bashing my head against the monitor for the past hour not knowing what I'm doing wrong. Thank you so much, you are a life saviour!

Comment: If this answer solved your problem please accept his answer and upvote if necessary

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understood correctly. Your only problem is `setTimeout` not working?
The first thing I noticed was that you closed an additional element of the button:

```html
  <div class="8ball">
    <button id="8bbtn" onclick="spin(); show();"> //finish button
      <video id="video1" width="800" controls>  //add controls
        <source src="./media/8ball.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      </video>
  </div>
```

And as for your question, you should call `setTimeOut` outside the function and then call your function inside it. It's like calling a function after the job is done. But you call it in `setTimeOut` because you need time.

```js
 var myVideo = document.getElementById("video1");
    var popup = document.getElementById("splashscrn");

    function spin() {
      myVideo.play();
    }

    function show() {
      popup.style.display = 'block';
    }

    setTimeout(show, 3000);
```

I hope this answer helped you.